# How to fix 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT' error in WordPress with WAMPSERVER installed?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm running up a local WordPress server with WAMPSERVER, and I'm working on editing the theme's child theme.

[image: WAMPSERVER DETAILS]

I also setup virtual server on my network. In the past few days I don't see any issue, everything work perfect. Until yesterday the virtual server look like not able to connect via my mobile phone and other computer in the same network.

Today I'm trying to work on the editing. It just can't load to the `homepage` or even `wp-admin`. So I took a look at the console in developer mode and I had this error.

[image: ERROR]

I have try to do all the research like changing the port at httpd.conf and wp_option in wordpress to localhost. It just don't work at all.

Comment: Hint: Virtual Host - ALWAYS for WordPress

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***

I have solve the issue with reinstall the WAMPSERVER and WordPress manually. I'll keep this post and make a guide for the future use.

Firstly I have no idea what to do because I can't even load to `/wp-admin`. So I decided to backup and restore everything manually.

**1. Backup directory**

Open up where your WordPress installed.

Click on the `WAMP` icon at the taskbar. If you don't see it probably is hidden inside the up arrow icon. Left click on the `WAMP` icon and navigate to `www directory`.

You don't need to copy and backup all the files in here. Navigate to `yoursite/wp-content` and copy `plugins`, `themes` and `uploads`.

Paste at any place in your computer as a backup except `C:\wamp64`. Because it will delete all the files when you uninstall the `WAMPSERVER`.

[image: backup-folder]

I'm using `WAMPSERVER 3.1.7`, older version might be different. Please Google `where is my www directory in wampserver replace.your.version` or original path which you can find at `C:\wamp64\www`.

[image: www-directory]

**2. Backup database**

We need to backup our database in order to recover the page, post or portfolio we created in the WordPress.

In your browser navigate to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and select your WordPress database at the right panel then select `export` button on the top and press `GO`. Make sure your `Format: SQL` before you press press the go.

All the pages, posts and portfolios that you created are store inside the database, not in the WordPress folder. Read more at [here](https://www.quora.com/Where-custom-pages-are-stored-in-wordpress).

[image: backup-db]

**Uninstall WAMPSERVER**

Update later...

**Reinstall WAMPSERVER**

Update later...

**Prepare to install WordPress**

Update later...

**Holla**

Update later...

Hope the above guide will solve your issue. I'm not a professional IT guy but it does work for me at least :).

Feel free to edit or suggest if you think I have mistake in the guide.